# Deploy Rails App on Centos Server - permission denied tmp/cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, nginx, passenger

I am trying to deploy my rails app on my centos server using nginx. I followed this guide : [Rails Deploy Guide Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-passenger-with-nginx-on-centos-6-5)

and now used sFTP to upload my app built on my development machine.

Whenever I call my site I get : `Errno::EACCES` `permission denied Permission denied - /var/www/my_app/tmp/cache/assets`

I tried to `chown -R root(:root) my_app` , I tried to `chmod 777 -R tmp` , `rake tmp:cache:clear`. It all does not work. I really don't know why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I re-installed the server and gave `tmp -R 777` rights and precompiled the assets. Now I get this error: `Error Compiling Assets CSS permission denied tmp/cache/assets/9DF  from usr/local/...ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby-2.0.0/fileutils.rb :245` in `mkdir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue after setting the owner of the folder to `nobody`. Even though the nginx owner flag is commented out by default `#nobody`, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be with `/var/www` not being writable for you. To write in `/dir1/dir2` you need to at least have execution grants to all the structure.

The ideal situation is to change `/var/www` to have 755 permissions.

More info in [Correct permissions for /var/www and wordpress](https://askubuntu.com/a/209547/143251).

Comment: Hi, my app folder is on 755 -R :).

Comment: @zer02 is not just this folder but all the structure. Show what are the permissions on all levels

Comment: what command should I use to show you? I also put `/var/www` on `755`. If you see my comment at my question I seems to have problem with creating dirs even with `777 -R on /tmp`.

Comment: @zer02 you can say `ls -ld /var /var/www /var/www/...`

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11  3 Jun 10:51 /var -> private/var`

Comment: I have no other group permissions then `root` for this nginx server. I just don't know why `fileutils.rb` can't `mkdir` a sub folder in `tmp/assets` .

Comment: @zer02 so `/var` is a symlink to `private/var`. Try to `mkdir in /var` and then continue. What is the error message you get when you say `chmod 777 -R tmp`?

Comment: It is running now, I changed `chown -R` to `nobody`. Everytime I restart nginx i have to reset tmp `chown`.

Comment: @zer02 well good to know something is solved, even though I am missing most of the information to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable SELinux http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

If it will help, make rule for sFTP client/your app.

Comment: Hi SELinux is disabled.